# Removing a single character from the beginning of file names

Tags: rename, file-management

File names :

```
_10_-_Overriding_or_customizing_the_rest_end_point-rkkfgI502f0.mp4
_11_-_Expose_ids_in_json_response-CrDXtLfiZos.mp4
_12_-_Create_angular_8_project_using_Angular_CLI-kSXkW1hF0KU.mp4
_13_-_Create_a_model_class_for_Book_entity-Hfm3da1Ze8E.mp4
_14_-_Display_the_list_of_books_in_html_table_with_hard-coded_values-b5R8CsMrOO4.mp4
_15_-_Create_a_new_book-list_component_and_display_the_book_images-Tto3r229fFA.mp4
_16_-_Make_a_HTTP_GET_request_to_the_Spring_boot_application-98RfVQ9Z3ZM.mp4
_17_-_Understanding_the_Observable_and_Observer-NKLirs5SFYk.mp4
_18_-_Call_a_service_method_to_get_the_book_array-yQ34aPdH1_0.mp4
_19_-_Fix_the_error_CORS_policy_and_display_the_data_in_html_table-YSEAdODxMfE.mp4
_1_-_Course_Introduction-b4pjjftApmY.mp4
_20_-_Replace_the_blank_images_with_real_images-fut1f40FHo4.mp4
_2_-_Setup_the_development_environment-RbUGvRAUpSM.mp4
_3_-_Setup_the_MySQL_database-D3krImBhofo.mp4
_4_-_Create_repository_in_Github_and_add_it_to_Eclipse_IDE-MAkVtB_MhzI.mp4
_5_-_Create_spring_boot_project_using_spring_initializer-GsmqGxEv6rg.mp4
_6_-_Configure_application_properties_and_commit_changes_to_github-HqDZKih-Ehk.mp4
_7_-_Create_an_entity_class_for_book_table-pfxt3BeU_e0.mp4
_8_-_Create_an_entity_class_for_book_table-eg1pJJLAzAQ.mp4
_9_-_Create_rest_repositories_for_book_and_category_entity-w7vFTSCWCOM.mp4
```

How can I remove the single `_` character from the beginning of the file names?

Comment: Are these filenames of files that you want to change in a directory, or are they stored in a text file, one per line?

Comment: They are in a directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the directory that contain those files, issue

```
for file in _*; do mv "$file" "${file#_}"; done
```

`${file#exp}` deletes the shortest match of the pattern `exp` from the beginning of `file`.

Comment: You could add `for file in _*.mp4` just to be thorough.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `rename` command (written by larry wall) it is part of Debian, and other distros. It allows the renaming of files, in the same way that `sed` allows transforming lines in a file.

So if sed would work on a line of text with `sed -i 's/^_//' file-name`.
Then rename will work on a file-name with `rename 's/^_//' file-name`.

Be sure to use the correct `rename`, there is more than one program with this name.